# How to Communicate with server in a Jetpack Compose App?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have made a simple Jetpack compose app coupled with a server. When I try to communicate with the server from the app, the app crashes without any error messages.

The app code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.Socket


fun getServerMessage(onServerMessage: (msg: String)-> Unit) {
    val client = Socket("127.0.0.1", 9999)
    val output = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
    val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.inputStream))

    output.println("msg")

    onServerMessage(input.readLine())
}

@Composable
fun GreetingFromServer(name: String) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("waiting for message") }

    thread { getServerMessage { msg -> text = msg } }

    Text(text)
}

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            GreetingFromServer("Android")
        }
    }
}
```

The server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.net.ServerSocket

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val server = ServerSocket(9999)
    println("printing")

    while (true) {
        val client = server.accept()
        println("a client connected")
        val output = PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true)
        val input = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(client.inputStream))

        output.println("${input.readLine()} back!")
    }
}
```

Why does the app crash when initiating the client object and when running the thread? And how should I go about fixing that?

(The app still crashes when removing the "thread {}" wrapping.)

Comment: You can only update the UI on the UI Thread. Your callback is on the background thread still.

Comment: If you are following the currently recommended app architecture, you can see that the code can be split into "UI, Data, and Domain" layers. Network communication happens at the data layer and the UI layer should not affect it. So Jetpack Compose and view based UI would handle network-related things in the same way.

Comment: I looked into the documentation to read about the different layers, but I still couldn't figure out. I realise that the UI should not effect the data layer. But how do I make it so that data sent from the server effects the UI?

Comment: @Abhimanyu (My last comment was meant to reply to you, but I didn't know I needed to use @ for that)

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the backend code, since the question was on Jetpack compose Android aspects, a simplified version of a network call would look something like this.

**API call**

```
suspend fun getServerMessage(): String {
    delay(5000)
    return "Success"
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
class GreetingFromServerViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var text by mutableStateOf("waiting for message")

    init {
        getMessage()
    }

    private fun getMessage() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            text = getServerMessage()
        }
    }
}
```

**View Composable**

```
@Composable
fun GreetingFromServer(
    viewmodel: GreetingFromServerViewModel = viewModel(),
) {
    Text(viewmodel.text)
}
```

Actual product apps would have a lot more things like using `Repositories` to manage data fetching, `Retrofit` if using REST APIs, etc.

Refer: [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines)